# Tracking state in URL params over multiple React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, urlsearchparams

I have a page which shows a list of items. These items are paginated, and can be searched, filtered, and ordered.

```
IndexComponent
-> SidebarComponent
   -> FilterComponentA
   -> OrderComponentB
-> ListContainerComponent
   -> SearchComponent
   -> PaginatedListComponent
```

There are several components here which have state related to the list which I want in the URL for page reload/URL sharing etc. The problem is that if we use `react-router`'s `useSearchParams()` hook over multiple components they all end up with different versions of the `searchParams` and end up overriding each other due to immutability.

What is the best way to handle this situation so that we have minimal re-renders or state changes, without having to hardcode in the child state into the parent components (SidebarComponent shouldn't need to know if we add an extra filter option)?

Comment: can we use context api?

Comment: @kritiz I did try it but it re-renders the page a LOT which also means it makes a lot of API calls

Comment: a bit more examples could be helpful to understand the scene

Comment: I don't think it's possible if someone hasn't posted any answer. I thought having shareable urls would be a common thing for a SPA, but apparently not. I'm guessing we would have to compromise and build a HOC which is aware of the variables we want to persist, or something